# ASP.NET Web API 2.0 Shared Model(for both API and client)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am new to ASP.NET Web API 2.0 . As per our requirement we need to have Web API that  will be consumed by 2 clients one in .NET(web app) another one Php(web app).

**No proxy concept for Web API :**

so that we decided that we can have the Shared models for both web api and .net Client.
But Php client need to create the model classes(request and response) again to use in php..

It might end up with some inconsistencies..Suppose models are changed in web api, need to update in php class model manually. Anyone have solution to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i would suggest you to use Data Transfer object project so there you will store all you models which you share.

Also manual fixing its a bit monkey thing :) and i would suggest you write simple mapper which will be runned on POST build and update php folder with generated files
Since your DTO will be just properties so lets say you have

```
public class SampleDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Title { get; set; }
    }
```

using code

```
var prop = typeof (SampleDto).GetProperties();
var php = "class " + typeof(SampleDto).Name + " {\n";
foreach (var propertyInfo in prop)
{
   php += "public $" + propertyInfo.Name + "; \n";
}
php += "}";
```

you will get php class

```
class SampleDto {
   public $Id; 
   public $Title; 
}
```

Now you can continue implementation and create exe file which you run on post build (In c# project) and it can load all you dto objects from librarry and write php classes to you folder